# Warning message while updating apk in playstore

Tags: android, google-play, android-build, google-location-services

I have one version of my app uploaded on playstore.I have to upload updated version of the app which now has location based services(fused location),hence i have permission check for Location.
While uploading google play shows a warning.

**!
New permissions added
WARNING
Users that have the APK with version code 14 may need to accept one or more of the android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions, which may result in them not upgrading to this version of the app.
TIP
Ensure that the new permissions are necessary, and consider mentioning these permissions in the What's new in this release text.**

Is this just a prompt or is this an issue that i need to handle?

Comment: check whether you need to use these permission or not? If not, just delete these permission and build again.

Comment: Ofcource i need permission to fetch location.

Comment: Its just a prompt that you are using location access permission in your app.

Comment: Ok thanx a ton @SunilP

Comment: *@SunilP* no it's not just a prompt, see *Aenadon* answer below.

Comment: meaning its just a intimation I guess from google that these permission are added to your project If necessary keep it or remove

Comment: Those applications with permission changes doesnot update automatically. User have to update them manually.

Answer (score 7):

This basically means that you added new permissions to your app and they will be displayed to the user when updating. There's a chance that some users will decline the update if they don't see the point of those new permissions, so you should think whether those permissions are really necessary and if yes, mention why in your changelog.

Comment: Device support removed
WARNING
Deactivation of this APK will result in your app being available for new installs on fewer types of devices.
TIP
If this is an unintended change, then retain this APK in the new release or ensure that your new APKs support all currently supported

what about this?

Comment: Google Play creates APK variants for different devices (Depending on processor type etc etc) so you should keep them in or it will be incompatible with some devices